# pass ajax values to paypal

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, paypal

I have a drop down menu.when select the option, it call ajax script and pass values from another php page according to the selection.
i want to pass that values to paypal account when click on paypal button.

Ajax

```
function showUser(id) {
    //get the selected value

    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_cat.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {option : id},
        success: function(data) {
           document.getElementById('cat_cost').innerHTML =data;

        }
    });
}
```

form

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"  method="post"> 
  <div >
    <select name="category" class="choose_list" onchange="showUser(this.value)"  >
      <?php
        $query= "SELECT * FROM requests
                   WHERE cat_action='Waiting'" ;
        $result= mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   
            echo '<option value="'.$row['package_id'].'">'.$row['cat'].'</option>';
        }
      ?>    
   </select>
 </div>

 <div  id="cat_cost">

 </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc@abc.com" />
        <?php /*?><input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $type; ?>" /><?php */?>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php  ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php  ?>" />
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this HTML

```
<select name="category" class="choose_list" id="select_choose_list">
  <?php
    $query= "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE cat_action='Waiting'" ;
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        echo '<option value="'.$row['package_id'].'">'.$row['cat'].'</option>';
    }
?>  
</select>
```

now in AJAX request

```
$('#select_choose_list').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax_cat.php&id=' + $('#select_choose_list').val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#cat_cost').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Try this :)

Comment: ajax pass values from ajax_cat.php.it's ok.but i want to do is pass those values to paypal.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="paypal_amt" name="amount" value="" />

Comment: $('#paypal_amt').val(data); //like this